# Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'String Heart Rate does not represent a valid UUID'

Tags: ios, uuid, core-bluetooth

I have discovered a peripheral service for Core Bluetooth in iOS with a value of "Heart Rate". I need to check when the CBUUID of the service equals "Heart Rate" by comparing the uuid property of the service to a CBUUID value of "Heart Rate". However, when I create the CBUUID object it generates a runtime error:

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'String Heart Rate does not represent a valid UUID'

at this code:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    var heartRateCBUUID = CBUUID(string: "Heart Rate") // error occurs here

    . . .

}
```

Here is the entire error message in the debug window:

```
2020-02-20 09:55:42.054190-0600 TrialCoreBluetoothWithXcode10[2186:469803] *** Assertion failure in -[CBUUID initWithString:], /BuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/MobileBluetoothFramework/MobileBluetooth-133.3/CoreBluetooth/CoreBluetooth/CBUUID.m:165
2020-02-20 09:55:42.057626-0600 TrialCoreBluetoothWithXcode10[2186:469803] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'String Heart Rate does not represent a valid UUID'
*** First throw call stack:
(0x1b1f52a48 0x1b1c79fa4 0x1b1e54e88 0x1b228a654 0x1c597101c 0x1c5971360 0x100755280 0x100756b74 0x100756e2c 0x1b5c783c0 0x1b556039c 0x1b54fcac8 0x1b5c7c3e4 0x1b556039c 0x1b55605d0 0x1b54fcac8 0x1b5c7745c 0x1b5c7a04c 0x1b612cea0 0x1b612cd34 0x1b5fd75e4 0x1b5fd7bd8 0x1b5fd6330 0x1b57a3208 0x1b5c39698 0x1b57a3cf0 0x1b57a3748 0x1b57a3b1c 0x1b57a33d8 0x1b57a78c4 0x1b5b6af08 0x1b5c52c84 0x1b57a75fc 0x1b5c52b80 0x1b57a7468 0x1b56192c0 0x1b5617e28 0x1b5618ff8 0x1b5fd47e4 0x1b5b8b900 0x1b70857a0 0x1b70aa838 0x1b708ff04 0x1b70aa4f4 0x100b0ebd8 0x100b11ffc 0x1b70cf418 0x1b70cf0e4 0x1b70cf60c 0x1b1ed0a00 0x1b1ed0958 0x1b1ed00f0 0x1b1ecb23c 0x1b1ecaadc 0x1bbe6b328 0x1b5fd863c 0x10075be08 0x1b1d54360)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
```

There was one question on stack**overflow** similar to this one, but it has no valid solutions.

Comment: if you haven't already, add exception breakpoint and make sure it breaks on throw. that will likely help you find the actual line of code responsible. additionally though its hard to tell what's going on if you don't include your code for creating the CBUUID

Comment: I'm not familiar with using exception breakpoints. I would like to learn that. Also, I put the wrong code in. I will fix that. The code I meant to put in my post is where the error actually occurs, which I will put in my post.

Comment: `CBUUID(string: "Heart Rate")` `Heart Rate` is not a valid UUID. Read the documentation: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corebluetooth/cbuuid/1519025-init Heart Rate is a known one, and should be `"180D"` (cf. https://www.bluetooth.com/specifications/gatt/services/)

Comment: google exception breakpoints if the following doesn't make sense, but basically on the left navigation panel in Xcode there's a breakpoint tab (second to last), press on that then go all the way to the bottom of the panel and there will be a +, add an exception breakpoint and make sure the break value is set to on throw. this will b v useful since it will stop on the crash and not on the main run loop like in your original code. (future note: sometimes it will break on handled exceptions, its not always on crashes, so if you're confused try pressing continue and seeing if it fixes itself)

Comment: @Larme Ok. I was thrown off because when I print the uuid property of the service of the peripheral device it says exactly “Heart Rate”.

Comment: Apple made the print of the "CBUUID" User Friendly. print the `cbuuid.uuidString` instead if needed. Example with `var heartRateCBUUID = CBUUID(string: "180D"); print(heartRateCBUUID.uuidString); print(heartRateCBUUID)` which prints `180D; Heart Rate`

Comment: @Larme That’s good idea. Thanks.